# Apache mod_rewrite/mod_redirect: convert URL with query parameters into an SEO-friendly URL. some query parameters are ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

As above.

might be best explained with an example:

- original URL (the order of the params is NOT consistent)

  - [www.myhost.com/my-page?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3](http://www.myhost.com/my-page?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3)
  - OR [www.myhost.com/my-page?p2=v2&p1=v1&p3=v3](http://www.myhost.com/my-page?p2=v2&p1=v1&p3=v3)
  - OR [www.myhost.com/my-page?p3=v3&p1=v1&p2=v2](http://www.myhost.com/my-page?p3=v3&p1=v1&p2=v2)
- If I visit any of the 3 sample URLs above, I want to get redirected to [www.myhost.com/my-page/v1/v2](http://www.myhost.com/my-page/v1/v2)

  - p3 was purposely ignored because it is not needed anymore.
  - in my real world URL, I have p4 to p6 parameters which are also ignored. I only wrote up to p3 for simplicity.

I've looked/searched the net but nothing comes close to what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)p1=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %1@%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^@]+)@(?:|.*&)p2=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/?(my-page)$ /$1/%1/%2 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The first *condition* captures the value of `p1` and passes this to the second *condition* that also captures the value of `p2`. These are then used in the *substitution* string as `%1` and `%2` backreferences respectively.

The URL parameters can occur in any order.

`@` (in the second condition) is just an arbitrary character that does not occur in `v1` and so is used as a delimiter between `v1` and the query string when searching for `p2`.

All other URL parameters (ie. `p3`..`pN`) are ignored (and discarded).

<del>Both `p1` and `p2` must exist with a non-empty value for the redirect to occur.</del>

**UPDATE:** `p1` must exist with a non-empty value (otherwise the resulting redirect will be ambiguous). `p2` must also exist, but the value can be *empty*. I've also updated the regex so that it would also allow an arguably malformed (but still valid) query string where the URL parameter delimiter (`&`) occurs before `p2` at the very start of the query string. eg. `/my-page?&p2=&p1=v1` would still be redirected to `/my-page/v1/`.

The `QSD` flag discards the original query string from the request.

Depending on where these directives are being used (eg. *directory* or *server* context) and how the URL is ultimately being routed, you may need to add an *initial condition* to ensure that only direct requests (as opposed to rewritten requests) are processed.

For example, add the following as the first condition if required:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
:
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> p1 and p2 are mandatory. p3 is optional.

You could change the above as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)p1=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %1@%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^@]+)@(?:|.*&)p2=([^&]+)
# Either p3 is mandatory and must have a value
RewriteCond %1/%2/@%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^@]+)@(?:|.*&)p3=([^&]+) [OR]
# OR p3 is omitted or does not have a value
RewriteCond %1/%2 (.+)
RewriteRule ^/?(my-page)$ /$1/%1%2 [QSD,R,L]
```

The 2nd condition now ensures there is a value for the `p2` parameter (ie. `v2`) - it cannot be empty.

Then either the 3rd condition checks for a non-empty `p3` parameter **OR** the 4th condition simply captures the values when the `p3` parameter is either empty or omitted altogether.

The resulting redirect omits the trailing slash when `p3` is not present. For example, the resulting redirect is either `/mypage/v1/v2` or `/mypage/v1/v2/v3`. (The trailing slash that might otherwise occur on `/mypage/v1/v2/` is avoided.)

In the final *substitution* string, the values of the `%1` and `%2` backreferences are a little different to before. These no longer contain each value (ie. `v1` and `v2`). Instead `%1` contains `v1/v2` and `%2` contains either `/v3` (including the slash prefix) or is *empty* (when `p3` is empty or omitted).

Comment: let me try. thank you

Comment: @mrjayviper I've updated my answer to allow an _empty_ (but still present) `p2` parameter. And to allow an arguably malformed (but still valid) query string where the URL parameter delimiter (`&`) occurs immediately before `p2` at the very start of the query string. eg. `/my-page?&p2=&p1=v1` (edge case).

Comment: I just realized p3 is now optional. what changes do I need to additional changes do I need to make? so p1 and p2 are mandatory. p3 is optional. Thank you.